# discordjs v13, command acces only to specific user id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
    if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "addbalance") && msg.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))
```

I need help changing command access from ADMINISTRATOR permission to only my discord id. I want to limitate the command only if I use it because I have many ADMINISTRATORS in my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the second condition in the `if` statement to check if the ID of the user is yours.

```js
if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "addbalance") && msg.member.id == YOUR_ID))
```

Comment: Working. Thank you so much!

Comment: @bmwturbopeek If this answer solved your problem please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when you can so it can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Why use `.member.user.id`? `.member.id` and `.author.id` both work equally well

Comment: @MrMythical Good point, I'm an old-school discord.js dev and I don't think GuildMember used to have an ID attribute a few years ago, so I did this out of habit. I've updated the post!